# GLUT substitute for AUX_RGBImageRec?

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm going through some old code that uses glaux everywhere.

Well, I'm required to use glut in my project, and I'm wondering if it has a structure for a rgb bitmap like glaux has.

Something that would allow me to replace this pointer declaration.

```
AUX_RGBImageRec *pBitmap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLUT doesn't have any replacement for image loading. SDL with SDL_image has it.

Answer (score 2):

Might give [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) a whirl.